# Exponents manipulation

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

When I type`(a^2)^s` Mathematica does not give me $a^{2s}$ instead it gives ${(a^2)}^s$. Is there a way to make it print $a^{2s}$.

It made some real difference where I wanted to compute

```
Sum[((n \[Pi]/T)^2)^-s, {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

vs

```
Sum[((n \[Pi]/T))^(-2 s), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

In the first case it gave me $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \pi ^{-2 s} \left(\frac{n^2}{T^2}\right)^{-s}$ but in the second case it gave me $\pi ^{-2 s} \left(\frac{1}{T}\right)^{-2 s} \zeta (2 s)$

I had to take the s-derivative of the result so I would like to get the result like the second one.

So, my question:

Is there any Mathematica function which helps me make Mathematica evaluate the first command and give back me the result like that of the second one?

Comment: Compare `(a^2)^s /. {a -> -1, s -> 1/2}` against `a^(2 s) /. {a -> -1, s -> 1/2}`.  Also consider `Simplify[(a^2)^s, Assumptions -> a > 0]`.

Comment: `(a^2)^s // PowerExpand` and `Sum[((n \[Pi]/T)^2)^-s // PowerExpand, {n, 1, Infinity}]` works.

Comment: To check if you are making some implied assumptions, use `FindInstance` to check for counterexamples, e.g., `FindInstance[(a^2)^s != a^(2s), {a, s}, 5]` and `FindInstance[(a^2)^s != a^(2s), {a, s}, Reals, 5]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FullSimplify[Sum[((n \[Pi]/T)^2)^-s, {n, 1, Infinity}],Assumptions->{T>0}]
```

Take your First input and assume $T>0$, that gives you the same result as the second one.